# How to install Google Play or other repo's on Waydroid?

Tags: google-play-store, installation, google-account, linux, virtualization

Having just installed `waydroid`, how is the Google Play Store installed?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo waydroid shell
/system/bin/sh: No controlling tty: open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
/system/bin/sh: warning: won't have full job control
:/ # 
:/ # whoami
root
:/ # 
:/ # exit
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ waydroid status
Session:    RUNNING
Container:  RUNNING
Vendor type:    MAINLINE
Session user:   nicholas(1000)
Wayland display:    wayland-0
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ waydroid --version
1.3.1
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

The [directions](https://docs.waydro.id/usage/install-and-run-android-applications) are:

```
waydroid app install xyz.apk
```

Which is easy enough.  However, there's no mention per se of installing the Google Play Store and secondary sources would indicate that alternates must be used.  Looking to install some sort of repository to pull in mainstream apps like `gmail`.

What repo's can be installed?

Comment: Google Play Store and Play services have to be installed as system apps, not as regular apps. Not sure how this can be done on waydroid. usually you have to modify the system image.

Comment: Trying https://auroraoss.com/ which has an apk for download..looks like the right thing.

Comment: AuroraOSS is a third party OSS app store (if it comes to OSS I would prefer F-Droid), even if you find GMail there it won't work without Play Services.

Comment: AuroraStore is just a FOSS front-end to Google Play (so it would work to get non-paid apps from there which, as pointed out, might not run properly if they require Google Services). AuroraDroid is the pendant for the F-Droid repositories. You can probably use both, yes. The term "Aurora Apps" just refers to these two apps, not to those you can access via AuroraStore ;)

Comment: So I would need Google Services to make Google Play Store work?  I'll look on FDroid for downloads.

Comment: You could install the GAPPS image (`sudo waydroid init -s GAPPS -f`) and register it.

Comment: @RafaelplayerxdYT Instructions unclear. I permanently broke my waydroid installation :D ! This might work for someone who hasn't ever installed any Android image. But as I already had Vanilla installed, this command did nothing, and there are apparently no way to re-initialize waydroid from scratch.

Comment: @Michael, that's what the -f do, it forces the image to change from your actual to a Google Services image (Google play won't work without Google services, at least not correctly), but once it finishes it will annoyingly beep on you because google doesn't recognize the device (and you won't be able to install anything), so you'll need to register the device to google to stop the beeps and install apps on Play Store